# bigquery how to get the jobreference of an insert job for a local CSV file

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I have a small piece of code to send a CSV file to a bigquery table.
The CSV file is on a local HD (not on google cloud storage).

Here is a simplified version of the csharp code (using version 2.1.5.0.122 of the bigquery csharp API).

```
    BigqueryService bq = someMethodToGetABigqueryServiceInstance();
    JobConfigurationLoad loadJobCfg = new JobConfigurationLoad();
    loadJobCfg.SourceFormat = "CSV";
    .
    .
    .
    Job job = new Job();
    JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
    config.Load = loadJobCfg;
    job.Configuration = config;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\onecol.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload insert = bq.Jobs.Insert(job, projectId, fs, "application/octet-stream");
    var progress = insert.Upload();
    // wait for Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Completed
    .
    .
```

The problem is that when I receive the Completed status, the file has been uploaded, but the data is not in the target table yet (ie: the job is still running).

Normally I should be able to wait for the job to be finished ('DONE') if I can have its reference (or ID),but I can't find a way to get that reference in the csharp API.

Is it possible to get the job reference from a JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload?
(insert.Body.JobReference is null)

Or is there another way to upload a local file to a bigquery table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend for all load jobs that you pass your own job reference -- that way in the event of a network hiccup, you'll be able to tell the state of the job. The job reference must be unique within the project, but this is pretty easy to do by creating a random number or using the current time.